# Set a column of a table to a SUM of a column of another table

Tags: mysql, sql

As title suggests: I have a table with a column that logically speaking should be the result of a SUM of a column from another table and I'd like to make it work like that so to not have inconsistent data inside the DB. How can I do this?

Comment: Hi. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) - although note that you wouldn't normally store derived data.

Comment: Why not just create a view to do this. Trying to keep a table updated based on another table can get ugly.

Answer (score 0):

The canonical answer is a trigger on the "other".  Or rather multiple triggers for inserts, updates, and deletes.

An alternative method is just to use a view:

```
create view v_t as
    select t.*, (select sum(ot.col) from othertable ot) as sum_other
    from t;
```

Because the value is recalculated when querying, the data is necessarily consistent.